# ASP.NET Core CS0535 Does not implement interface

Tags: c#, service, asp.net-core-2.1

Sorry for noob question because new in ASP.NET Core.
I have the problem that indicate CS0535
CS0535
'UserInfoService' does not implement interface member 'IUserInfoService.UpdateLogoutTime(string)'
Community.Service
D:\repo\Community\Community.Service\Users\UserInfoService.cs
23
Active

Error CS0535 'UserInfoService' does not implement interface member 'IUserInfoService.UpdateLoginTime(string)' Community.Service D:\repo\Community\Community.Service\Users\UserInfoService.cs 23 Active

```
public async Task UpdateLoginTimeAsync(string userId)
{
    var user = _dbIdentity.Users.Where(x => x.Id == userId).FirstOrDefault();
    user.LoginTime = DateTime.Now;
    _dbIdentity.Users.Update(user);
    await _dbIdentity.SaveChangesAsync();
}

public async Task UpdateLogOutTimeAsync(string userId)
{
    var user = _dbIdentity.Users.Where(x => x.Id == userId).FirstOrDefault();
    user.LogoutTime = DateTime.Now;
    _dbIdentity.Users.Update(user);
    await _dbIdentity.SaveChangesAsync();
}
```

```
using Community.Data.CommonDataTypes;
using Community.Data.Entities.Companies.ViewModels;
using Community.Data.Entities.Users;
using Community.Data.Entities.Users.ViewModels;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace Community.Service.Users
{
    public interface IUserInfoService
    {
        CompanyRoleViewModel GetCompanyRole();

        Task<IEnumerable<CompanyRoleViewModel>> GetAllCompanyRolesAsync(long companyID);

        Task<CompanyRoleViewModel> GetCompanyRoleAsync(string companyRoleId);

        Task<ServiceSingleRecordInsertOrUpdateResponse> CreateCompanyRoleAsync(CompanyRoleViewModel model, long companyId);

        Task<ServiceSingleRecordInsertOrUpdateResponse> UpdateCompanyRoleAsync(CompanyRoleViewModel model);

        Task ApproveUserAccountsOfCompanyAsync(long companyId);

        Task<ServiceStatusResponse> DeleteUserAsync(string userId);

        Task<int> RetrieveNumberOfUsersAsync();

        Task<IEnumerable<UserInfo>> RetrieveAllUsersAsync(bool includingInactive = false);

        Task<string> GenerateCsvContentForAllUsersAsync(bool includingInactive = false);

        Task<UserInfo> RetrieveUserInfoAsync(string userId);

        Task<UserInfo> RetrieveUserInfoWithoutCompanyByPhoneNumberAsync(string phoneNumber);

        Task<UserInfo> RetrieveUserInfoByEmailAsync(string userEmail);

        Task<ServiceStatusResponse<UserInfo>> RetrieveUserInfoByPhoneNumberAsync(string phoneNumber);

        Task<string> RetrieveUserFullNameByEmailAsync(string userEmail);

        Task<CompanyProfileManageViewModel> RetrieveUserCompanyInfoByEmailAsync(string userEmail);

        Task<long> RetrieveCompanyIdByEmailAsync(string userEmail);

        Task<IEnumerable<UserInfo>> RetrieveInfoOfAllUsersInCompanyAsync(long companyId);

        Task<List<UserIdEmailViewModel>> RetrieveIdEmailOfAllUsersInCompanyAsync(long companyId);

        Task<List<UserIdEmailFullNameViewModel>> RetrieveIdEmailFullNameOfAllUsersAsync(bool includingInactive = false);

        Task<string[]> RetrieveEmailsOfAllUsersInCompanyAsync(long companyId);

        Task<IEnumerable<UserInfo>> RetrieveInfoOfAllSuperUsersAsync();

        Task<bool> SubmitNewUserAccountCreationRequest(NewUserAccountCreationRequestViewModel model, string createdBy);

        Task<NewUserAccountCreationRequest> RetrieveNewUserAccountCreationRequestAsync(string userEmail);

        Task<ServiceSingleRecordInsertOrUpdateResponse> UpdateUserAsync(CompanyUserManageViewModel model, string actionUser);

        Task<ServiceStatusResponse> UpdateUserPhoneNumberAndUserNameAsync(string userId, string phoneNumber);

        Task<bool> SetUserAccountCreationRequestAsDoneAsync(string userEmail);

        Task<ServiceSingleRecordInsertOrUpdateResponse> AttachUserToAnotherCompany(string currentUserId, long currentCompanyId, long targetCompanyId);

        Task<ServiceSingleRecordInsertOrUpdateResponse> DetachUserFromCompanyBackToOriginalCompany(string currentUserId, long currentCompanyId, string currentCompanyName);

        Task<DateTime> UpdateLoginTime();

        Task<DateTime> UpdateLogoutTime();
    }
}
```

Thanks for the help.

Comment: It seems your interface does not have async signature but in class it is async.  Can you post interface code as well ?

Comment: @ManojChoudhari adding the interface

Comment: `UpdateLogoutTime` is not the same method name as `UpdateLogoutTimeAsync`.

Comment: The posted error message and the posted code do not match. Please provide your current code.

Answer (score 0):

You should implement your interface's UpdateLoginTime(string) member as described in error message. You should type your error code, which is CS0535 into searchbar of Google and then you can find [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/misc/cs0535)

Answer (score -1):

Use the potential fixed in Visual Studio, it will automatically adding the following code:

```
        Task<UserInfo> IUserInfoService.UpdateLoginTimeAsync(string userId)
        {
            throw new NotImplementedException();
        }

        public Task<UserInfo> UpdateLogoutTimeAsync(string userId)
        {
            throw new NotImplementedException();
        }
```